# Orthogonality Condition

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Consider the set
$$
Z_n = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \; | \; x^\top y = 0 \rbrace.
$$
It is easy to see that
$$
Z_1 = \lbrace (x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \rbrace \cup \lbrace (0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \rbrace
$$
is contained in a finite union of hyperplanes. Does the same hold true for $n \geq 2$?

Answer (score 1):

$$f_x(y):y\in \mathbb{R}^n\to x^Ty$$
so $Z_n=\{(x,f_x^{-1}(0)), x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}=\{(0,y), y\in \mathbb{R}^n\} \cup \{(x,f_x^{-1}(0)), x\neq 0,x\in \mathbb{R}^n \}$
 since for any $x$ one can construct non zero $y$ with $x^Ty=0$ and vise versa, this is the form of $Z_n$.